# Executing JPanelForm from Main class in java

Tags: java, swing, jform

i am bit new in java what i want to achieve is, I have 2 java classes in same package.

`CodeAnalyzer.java` and `CodeReader.java`

`CodeReader` is the `Jform` class in which i have made `JFileChooser`, now i want to execute `CodeReader` with the execution of `CodeAnalyzer`.

Source code of CodeAnalyzer is Below

```
public class CodeAnalyzer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
}

}
```

Comment: Don't down vote only if you don't find my english good !

Comment: It's not because of your english but because you lack a proper [mcve] and you're showing little to no effort in solving it by yourself.

Comment: Well i solved the by my own.

Comment: It's a good practice to answer your own question and explain how you solved it, in case someone else has the same problem, then he can do the same you did. Also, you should [edit] your own post adding the code when it wasn't working. Good luck!

Comment: They downvote because SO is a MMORPG... "I have enough points to secretly downvote, so I will'. Also, Java is a language that people use to make money. They are afraid to become jobless, because they teach a beginner and beginner is better than them. SO is a wrong place to search for answers or respect...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CodeAnalyzer {
CodeReader cr;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     cr = new CodeReader();
   }
}
```

Just make an Object of your CodeReader and if it executes a Code which promts a Window it'll do it

Comment: I did this and it worked.. ?
  `   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CodeReader codeReader = new  CodeReader();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(codeReader);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });`

Comment: Erm is this a part of your code ? could you add this to the description?
In the comments it's unreadable ....

Comment: `   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Runnable() {`

            
           `public void run() {`
               ` CodeReader codeReader = new  CodeReader();`
               `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`
                `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`
               ` frame.getContentPane().add(codeReader);`
               ` frame.pack();`
               ` frame.setVisible(true);`
          `  }`
        `});`

Comment: I mean edit your question please :) and I am not 100% sure what your problem is now? didn't it worked?

Comment: lol you're confunsing me a bit :'D you need help now or not? o:

Comment: If you describe your problem further I may can help you ^^